# Angular *ngFor over FormGroup in Template - Cannot find a differ supporting object error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to loop over a FormGroup of FormControls in the template. I want to display a checkbox for each.
This is how my component.ts looks like

```
tags = ["vegan","vegetarian","meat","fruit","vegetable","seafood","fish","nut"];

get tagsForForm() {
    return this.foodForm.get('tags') as FormGroup;
}

createTagsForForm(): {[key: string]: any} {
    let tagsForForm = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tags.length; i++){
        tagsForForm[this.tags[i]]=false;
    }
    return tagsForForm;
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.foodForm = this.fb.group({
        foodName: [''],
        tags: this.fb.group(this.createTagsForForm())
    });
}
```

My template.html looks like this:

```
<section formGroupName="tags">
    <h2>Tags</h2>
    <input *ngFor="let tag of tagsForForm" [formControlName]="tag" type="checkbox">
</section>
```

In the console I'm getting this error:

```
"Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."
```

Is it not possible to loop over a FormGroup in the template or is only something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe to loop over objects. Try the following

```html
<input *ngFor="let tag of tagsForForm | keyvalue" [formControlName]="tag.value" type="checkbox">
```

The value of the property is available in `tag.value` and the key of the property is available in `tag.key`.

**Update**

It appears `this.foodForm.get('tags') as FormGroup` doesn't return the correct object to loop over. You could try to replace it with `this.foodForm.controls['tags']['controls'];`. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  foodForm: FormGroup;
  tags = ["vegan", "vegetarian", "meat", "fruit", "vegetable", "seafood", "fish","nut"];

  get tagsForForm() {
    return this.foodForm.controls['tags']['controls'];
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  createTagsForForm(): {[key: string]: any} {
    let tagsForForm = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tags.length; i++){
      tagsForForm[this.tags[i]] = false;
    }
    return tagsForForm;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foodForm = this.fb.group({
      foodName: [''],
      tags: this.fb.group(this.createTagsForForm())
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<form [formGroup]="foodForm">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input formControlName="foodName" />
    <section [formGroup]="foodForm.controls.tags">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tagsForForm | keyvalue">
      <label>{{ tag.key | titlecase }}</label>
      <input [formControlName]="tag.key" type="checkbox">
      <br>
    </ng-container>
  </section>
</form>
```

Alternatively if you're generating the nested form group using a member variable (`tags` here), you could loop over it to avoid the getter and some additional overhead. The following would also work

```html
<form [formGroup]="foodForm">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input formControlName="foodName" />
    <section [formGroup]="foodForm.controls.tags">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tags">
      <label>{{ tag | titlecase }}</label>
      <input [formControlName]="tag" type="checkbox">
      <br>
    </ng-container>
  </section>
</form>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfywwsc57)

Comment: Ok thank, but now I'm getting ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'tags -> () => { }'" in the console and "Argument of type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Map<unknown, unknown>'.
          Type 'FormGroup' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<unknown, unknown>': clear, delete, forEach, has, and 7 more." in the Terminal

Comment: There is an issue with the getter. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

use keyvalue pipe as you are using object instead of array

```
<input *ngFor="let tag of tagsForForm| keyvalue" [formControlName]="tag.value" type="checkbox">
```

use this link for more info https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe